# System vs Local Environment in Rakefile

Tags: ruby, rake

We're using `rake` for some setup steps. We need to make sure that a particular directory is in the PATH, and we've used this in `Rakefile` to do so:

```
  hasImageMagic =  ENV["Path"] =~ /ImageMagick/
  if not hasImageMagic ...
```

When run `Rake` under `git-bash`, this works fine.

When we run `Rake` run under `Powershell` however, this fails to find the element in our `Path`. We've found that it's looking at the user's local Path rather than the system path.

[image: local vs system PATH variables on Windows]

Does `ruby` have a way to look at the *system* path variable?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced.

Comment: Although "nothing's been changed" (yea, right; but verifiable via git), the same code is working fine today. `ENV["Path"]` is combining local and system environment vars, and all's well with the world.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`GetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable(v=vs.110).aspx) method to specify that it's a machine-wide environment variable you're interested in:

```
$PathVar = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path",[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

if($PathVar -notmatch "ImageMagick"){
    # error handling here
}
```

Comment: that's Powershell script, right? I was unclear in my question - I'm looking for Ruby, to be part of our existing `Rakefile`.

Comment: @StevenV Yes this is PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

@StevenV sorry, this is my fault. I had originally written this code and only tested it in gitbash:

```
hasImageMagic =  ENV["Path"] =~ /c:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-/
if not hasImageMagic ...
```

While that worked fine in gitbash, I was later alerted by another team member that this did not work as expected in powershell. I then pushed the code you posted in your question, and it does seem to work with powershell:

```
hasImageMagic =  ENV["Path"] =~ /ImageMagick/
if not hasImageMagic ...
```

I am personally still in the dark as to why gitbash liked the original regex but powershell did not. This is my first ruby code ever, so mea culpa.